# SharePoint 2010 values from the Site Parameters in Site Options

Tags: 2010

How can I get access to the parameters in SharePoint 2010's Site Options / Parameters area from a site page? I am looking to create a global variable to use in constructing a querystring and wasn't sure how to get this parameters value back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to open the web for your specific site and then use get it using all Properties

```
    using(SPWeb siteCollection = currentInstance.OpenWeb())
    {
         if(siteCollection.AllProperties.ContainsKey("Your key name"))
             return (string) siteCollection.AllProperties("Your Key Name");
    }
```